# is there a way to define a function in datatables order?

Tags: datatables

Actually, I have 2 tables (pending and published) using datatables on the same page.

The order API , as I know, allows to choose only columns and sorting direction.

My data are sorted now depending on closing date for both tables

```
order : [ 5, "desc" ]
```

Is there a way to choose the sorting column depending on the result of a function? For exemple:

order : function(){

```
if(tab == 'pending'){
    return [4, "desc"]; // sort publication date column
} else {
    return [5, "desc"]; // sort closing date column
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have relevant information in top result of this search: https://www.google.com/search?q=datatable+custom+order

Comment: Thank you @Dani Actually I found the solution. I added "table.order([4, 'asc']).draw();" inside initComplete function and it worked